# Getting error in Flatten Azure Data flow?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am having a below column called"Assigned To" in my dataset

[image]

I am trying to split this column using a delimiter in the derived column
(split({Assigned To}, ";")) and it's converting into Array

When I tried to use Flatten to convert into multiple rows, I am getting the below error message

[image]

Not sure why this error coming? I believe some of the rows in my data have only one value example, Smith only name presents in the first row and the same goes for Jim in the fourth row. Is this error happening because of this one value in the array? Can anyone advise how to overcome this?

I need output like below

[image]

I can see the results preview in the derived flow

[image]

This is my Flatten flow

[image]

Getting this error

[image]

Comment: Hi, Can you please provide a sample of your expected output?

Comment: @NiharikaMoola-MT added an expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have reproed it with your sample data and it worked fine for me. Make sure to provide the correct column to the **Unroll** in **Flatten settings**.

> When you are using flatten, make sure you do not have space in the column name

1. Source:

[image]

2. Derived Column:

Expression: `split({Assigned To}, ';')`

[image]

3. Flatten transformation:

[image]

Flatten data preview:

[image]

4. You can remove unwanted columns using Select transformation if needed.

Comment: Thanks for your time and explanation. I followed exactly the same and got the same error. One thing I noted my column has null values. Is the error because of the null values? I uploaded my flatten and derived column result. I can see the preview in the derived column result. Please advise

Comment: @Niharikaoola-MT -- Thanks. It's working. I have not given a new column name. Thanks a lot and it's working